# Odd error while using openssl

Tags: openssl

When I use openSSL and a config file to sign a intermediate certificate I constantly get the same error. The errors are:

`140736005481480:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:175:fopen('/Volumes/Project - Encrypted/Security/root/ca/index.txt.attr','rb')`

`140736005481480:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:182:`

`140736005481480:error:0E078072:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:no such file:conf_def.c:195:`

`140736005481480:error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value:conf_lib.c:324:group=CA_default name=email_in_dn`

I understand the first error about the file not being found, but what I dont understand is why the file its looking for isn't the file i define in the config.
This is what I put in the config:

`database       = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.`

The command I use is `sudo openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions v3_intermediate_ca       -days 3650 -notext -md sha256   -keyfile private/ca.key.pem  -cert certs/ca.cert.pem  -in intermediate/csr/intermediate.csr.pem       -out intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem`

Does anyone understand whats causing these error and how to fix them??

Answer (score 9):

`openssl ca` doesn't just use the database index file (which you have correctly set to be `index.txt`) but als a *database attribute* file. This is always in the same place as the index file and its name is that of the index suffixed with *.attr*. This attribute file (which is not really documented, as far as I know) holds only one information: The configuration line

```
unique_subject = yes/no
```

So what do you need to do? Create the file `index.txt.attr` in the folder where your CA is stored (appearantely */Volumes/Project - Encrypted/Security/root/ca*) and add to it the single line I mentioned above.

Comment: I have haven’t had a chance to test it, but I’m asuming it’s going to work. What does “unique_subject” do?

Comment: `openssl ca` doesn't actually need the `attr` file; it uses a default, and then (re)creates the `attr` file after processing (in `save_index`). But it does leave spurious 'error' info in the error stack, which gets added to the display for any real error that occurs. And similarly for `email_in_dn` whose absence is actually ignored but still pollutes the stack. I don't know what the real error was here but it wasn't either/any of the 'errors' in the Q.

Comment: @Matt121: unique_subject is explained in the man page for `ca` on your system [also on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/ca.html)